# Passing value from jQuery mobile 1.4.2. to another page using php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mobile

So i got this slider and placed the value in a hidden input, here is the code for the html en js part

```
<form id="sliderFrame" action="mmd_pijn_add_3.php" method="post">
   <input type="hidden" id="hiddenInputSlider" name="hiddenInputSlider"> 
   <input data-show-value="true" name="slider" id="slider" data-highlight="true" min="0" max="10" value="0" type="range"> 
</form>

$(document).ready(function(){
   $('#slider').bind("change", function(){
       $("#hiddenInputSlider").text($(this).val());
    });  
 });
```

As for the php code i have this:

```
<?php
   session_start();
   $valueSlider = ; => how to get the value in here
   $_SESSION['hiddenInputSlider'] = $valueSlider;
?>
```

All the above code is on the index.php page, on the second page i echo out the $_SESSION['hiddenInputSlider'] and it returns obviously NULL

So my question is how to get the value of the slider in to the php variable $valueSlider

Answer (score 0):

You send your form via method `POST`. So use `$_POST` array in your php script (in `mmd_pijn_add_3.php`.

So yor php file `mmd_pijn_add_3.php` contents:

```
<?php
   session_start();
   $valueSlider = $_POST['hiddenInputSlider'];
   $_SESSION['hiddenInputSlider'] = $valueSlider;
?>
```

You send form with some data. You have some fields with name attributes. This data will be sent. After that you can access it from arrays `$_GET`, `$_POST` or `$_REQUEST` (get if get method; post if post method; response array contains both data sent via post or get methods).

Comment: What output? You didn't output anything in your code. Updated your code, provide php code and js

Comment: check now i resketched the situation to make the issue more clear, any help is welcome

Answer (score 0):

The index.php page looks like this:

```
<?php
      session_start();
      $valueSlider = $_POST['hiddenInputSlider'];
      $_SESSION['hiddenInputSlider'] = $valueSlider;
?><!DOCTYPE html>
  <html>
  <head> 

  <script>
     $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#slider').bind("change", function(){
            $("#hiddenInputSlider").text($(this).val());
        });  
     });
  </script>

  </head>
  <body>
       <form id="sliderFrame" action="mmd_pijn_add_3.php" method="post">
         <input type="hidden" id="hiddenInputSlider" name="hiddenInputSlider"> 
         <input data-show-value="true" name="slider" id="slider" data-highlight="true" min="0" max="10" value="0" type="range">                            
      </form>
  </body>
  </html>
```

The second page where the form is send to mmd_pijn_add_3.php, there i echo out the session

```
 <?php
      session_start();
      echo $_SESSION['hiddenInputSlider'];
  var_dump($_SESSION['hiddenInputSlider']); 
 ?>
```